# Как получить id подкатегорий в главной категории opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

в файле `/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl`

```
<?php if ($categories) { ?>

    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
            <?php echo $category['name']; ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>

<?php } ?>
```

Не могу найти место, где формируется массив `$categories`. Так как сейчас в массиве не передается `id` подкатегории...

Подскажите как получить `id` подкатегорий при переборе массива `$categories`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался.

В `/catalog/controller/product/category.php`

После

```
'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url),
```

Добавил

```
'category_id'  => $result['category_id']
```